# Mac startup sound keeps coming back to haunt me

Tags: macos, terminal, startup, sound-volume

Seriously though, even after applying the terminal command (below) *that sound* will be back after x numbers of shutdowns or restarts:

```
sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80
```

I'd appreciate a *truly* permanent answer to silencing that startup sound.

Comment: "x" would be helpful to know.  Could it possibly be that it comes back after an update is applied?

Comment: Try ```sudo nvram -c``` and then try applying ```sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80```. Also, from what I understand, you don't want that startup sound. This can also be done by muting your speakers when macOS is booted. You can turn them back on but you need to silence them before shutting down.

Comment: @Allan x from my experience has been a random number - it could quite literally appear next restart or go for weeks without an issue

Comment: Random is super difficult to diagnose because there's nothing that would override those changes unless you update.  Try resetting the NVRAM first, write the new value, then test it out.  Mark a tick on a small piece of paper to keep track of reboots between when you set it and when it resets itself.  Then you can start looking at logs to see what changed.

Comment: The other option would be write a `launchd` script that sets the value every day at some interval so it's always there.

Comment: Not familiar with launchd scripts, is there documentation to do as you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a free application called [Deeper by Titanium Software](https://titanium-software.fr/en/deeper.html). You can download it from [this link here](https://titanium-software.fr/en/deeper.html), or by using homebrew cask in which you can enter the following terminal command after installing homebrew/homebrew cask:

```
brew cask install deeper
```

Once you have installed deeper and allowed it proper privilages, open it up and go to the "Login Tab". From there you will see a button to turn off your mac's startup sound. [image]Click it and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks - newish to Macos, isn't the app doing the same thing as what was done in the terminal?

Comment: I'm not sure how the developers program it, but I would think its safe to assume the app executes some sort of termincal command. Maybe a different one that holds the settings. Not to sure otherwise. Did you try this yet?

Comment: OK - I have installed now, I can update here if something comes up or try the plan b of brew install.

Comment: @PeterAskins keep me updated.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, several restarts, all with sound.

Comment: @PeterAskins Just looking over my old posts. There has to be a command line tool to accomplish this. i will do some investigating

Comment: OK, currently just hacking it by having volume down, anyway many thanks.